# ReactJS получить CSS-стиль родителя

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html

Добрый день всем, есть ли возможность в react.js получить стиль родительского компонента, например:
Parent компонент:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="myField">
                    <MyComponent />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Child компонент:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <svg width="100%" height="100%">
            </svg>
        )
    }
}
```

В данной ситуации я хотел бы получить CSS-стиль(а именно width и height) div'а "myField". Возможно ли такое? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте, сам только изучаю react.
Я бы сделал так - в Parent Component определил бы нужный css стиль

```
let computedStyle = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('myField'));
let width = computedStyle.width;
```

а потом передал бы это свойства в Child Component

```
<MyComponent width={width} />
```

Либо можно определение стиля сделать функцией и передавать в Children Component функцию, а там уже запускать ее и получать значение свойства, когда нужно.

Comment: Добрый день, решил проблему данным образом:

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо за комментарий. Решил проблему данным образом получаю высоту и ширину компонента через `findDOMNode`:  

`this.fSize.svgBlock.width = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().width;`